# Splitting a sentence based on group of words declared in an array

Tags: python-3.x

I have declared some words in a array and looped over it such that if that particular word is present in the input sentence it should be splitted with that word accordingly..

```
arr_utility = [' my names',
   'my name is ',
   'name ',
   ' names ']



if any(c in str for c in arr_utility):
      print('\nUtility Identified')
      res = str.split(arr_utility[c])
      print(res[1])
else:
      print('No Utility Found')
```

Input: Hello my name is rahul
Output : rahul

Im getting that the word is present in the input but its not splitting

Answer (score 1):

I would code it as follows:

```
string = "Hello my name is rahul"
arr_utility = [' my names',
   'my name is ',
   'name ',
   ' names ']

for substring in arr_utility:
    if substring in string:
        res = string.split(substring)
        print(res[1])
        break
else:
    print('No Utility Found')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ..Problem Solved

Answer (score 0):

**Use word boundaries to search exact words inside the haystack string** `("Hello my name is rahul")`.

---

To create a simple word boundary you can use the [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search):

```
# this will output None
>>> re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(' my names'), 'Hello my name is rahul')
    None

# this will match uniquely
>>> a = re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format('my name is '), 'Hello my name is rahul')
>>> print (a)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 17), match='my name is '>
```

So you have to just get the first index out of the match.

---

**A complete example:**

```
import re

str = "Hello my name is rahul"
arr_utility = [' my names',
   'my name is ',
   'name ',
   ' names ']

res = [str.split(word)[1] for word in arr_utility if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), str) is not None]

for outer_list in res:
    for inner_list in outer_list:
        print(inner_list[1])
```